# How to access the HTTP/2 stream id in the send callable to the asgi app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http2, asgi

I'm building an ASGI application server in python and implementing the HTTP/2 protocol. I receive raw bytes from a socket, parse the bytes and convert them into frame objects. When I trigger the ASGI application the send callable only gets an event dict as a parameter which does not contain the stream id. Since, I'm using async/await my server could be handling multiple streams simultaneously. How do I know which stream id to associate with which send callable?

```py
class Server(object):
  async def send_response(self, event):
    # event dict does not contain stream id
    if event["type"] == "http.response.start":
      # Need stream id here to create http2 frames
      ...
    elif event["type"] == "http.response.body":
      # Need stream id here to create http2 frames
      ...

  async def handle_request(self):
    try:
      while True:
        self.request_data = self.client_connection.recv(4096)
        self.frame = self.parse_request(self.request_data)

        if isinstance(self.frame, HeadersFrame):
          # stream id is available here as self.frame.stream_id
          if self.frame.end_stream:
            asgi_scope = self.get_asgi_event_dict(self.frame)
            self.asgi_app = self.application(asgi_scope)
            await self.asgi_app(self.trigger_asgi_application, self.send_response)
```

I want to be able to get stream id in the send_response function.